# What is the current maximum disk size for Persistent Disk

Tags: google-cloud-platform

On Coursera's material, it states 64TB.
On Google's console, it states ~65TB.
On Google's documentation, it states 64TB.

Can I safely assume Google's console is the updated and correct one? Or there is a different usage for the additional 1TB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are true!! All depends how you count the bytes.

- if 1kb = 1000 bytes, the max size disk is 64Tb
- If 1kb = 1024 bytes, the max size disk is 65.536Tb (64/1000*1024)

Comment: I'm new to computing and I didn't know about 1kb = 1000 bytes. Thanks! Learn something new everyday. While there are two ways to count the bytes, in general, is there a way to know which calculation is adopted? or Cloud computing will always use 1kb = 1000bytes?

Comment: There is no norm or convention. Depends on the context. If you wand to buy a SSD, sometime you can see 128Gb, sometime 132Gb. You can say: Hey this one is bigger!!! But not.... You need to be aware of that!!!